# Default checked is not working for Html.RadioButtonFor

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Html radio button for my model value and I want default check for radio button, but it's not working:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Answer, 1, new { id = @item.ID, @checked = "checked" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Answer, 2, new { id = @item.ID + "_1"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Answer, 3, new { id = @item.ID + "_2" })
```

It render as

```
<input data-val="true"  id="8" name="Answer" type="radio" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know :

`Html.RadioButtonFor` Define:

```
Html.RadioButtonFor(model => property, object value, object htmlAttributes)
```

Object `HtmlAttributes`: Set additional properties to a radio button.

`Html.RadioButton` Define:

```
RadioButton(string name, object value, bool isChecked, object htmlAttributes)
```

Bool `isChecked`: Set default radio button selection

> I want default check for radio button

You can try:

```
  @Html.RadioButton("Answer", 1,true,new { id = 8 })
```

result:
[image]